# How do I make a grid 4 column shrink to 1 column while using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want my 4 columns to become one when I shrink the page in bootstrap as in the picture.

```
<div class="container-fluid ">
     <div class="row my-row ">
         <div class="col col-md-3 my-col">
            <div style="height: 400px; background-color: rgb(26, 188, 156);"></div>
             column
         </div>
         <div class="col col-md-3 my-col">
            <div style="height: 400px; background-color: rgb(26, 188, 156);"></div>
             column
         </div>
         <div class="col col-md-3 my-col">
            <div style="height: 400px; background-color: rgb(26, 188, 156);"></div>
             column
         </div>
         <div class="col col-md-3 my-col">
            <div style="height: 400px; background-color: rgb(26, 188, 156);"></div>
            
             <div><p>column</p></div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

[image]

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Add the class `col-xs-12` to it. Then, at small sizes, each item is 12 units across (the entire page), but at medium screen sizes, it goes back to just 3 units wide.

Comment: I wouldn't just add an `-xs-` class. It's best to use a default width class (e.g. `col-12`) and then to add responsive classes (e.g. `col-md-3`) on top, so that it's completely clear what will happen at all widths. There's more info in my answer below.

Comment: The way I want it is so that when I shrink the page the other 3 columns disappear and only one of them shows at the size that it was

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "how do I properly use responsive classes so that the layout is in 1 column at narrow widths but 4 columns when it's wider?" In which case, you change your classes to something like `col-12 col-lg-3` (remembering that the numbers in the classes show how many notional columns the element should use up, based on Bootstrap's standard 12-column grid).

The code would end up looking something like this. I've added an extra `md` breakpoint here, to hopefully help make it clear how it all works.

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row my-row">
         <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 my-col">
            STUFF
         </div>
         <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 my-col">
            STUFF
         </div>
         <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 my-col">
            STUFF
         </div>
         <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 my-col">
            STUFF
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

In essence, when building a Bootstrap layout, you need to think about the breakpoints of your structure. Start with a default layout for your mobile (narrowest) layout and add the necessary default `col-*` class (here, `col-12` because you want each `div` to use all 12 notional columns - i.e. you want each to be full-width). Then consider where you want the layout to change and add a new `col-xx-*` class for that breakpoint (here, `col-md-6` to go to 2 columns at the medium size and `col-lg-3` to go to 4 columns at the large size). Bootstrap will use the `col-12` up to the first breakpoint you specify and then use the new width from that breakpoint upwards, and similarly for each breakpoint in size order.

Comment: The way I want it is so that when I shrink the page the other 3 columns disappear and only one of them shows at the size that it was

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="container-fluid ">
 <div class="row my-row ">
     <div class="col-3 col-md-3 my-col">
        <div style="height: 400px; background-color: rgb(26, 188, 156);"></div>
        <p>column</p>
     </div>
     <div class="d-none d-sm-block col-md-3 d-sm-none d-md-block my-col">
        <div style="height: 400px; background-color: rgb(26, 188, 156);"></div>
         column
     </div>
     <div class="d-none d-sm-block col-md-3 d-sm-none d-md-block my-col">
        <div style="height: 400px; background-color: rgb(26, 188, 156);"></div>
         column
     </div>
     <div class="d-none d-sm-block col-md-3 d-sm-none d-md-block my-col">
        <div style="height: 400px; background-color: rgb(26, 188, 156);"></div>
        
         <div><p>column</p></div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

This is how it is done. Thanks for all help!

Comment: OK, glad you sorted it out. You can still improve your CSS here, though. You have overlapping classes (`d-sm-block` sets `display: block`, then `d-sm-none` sets `display: none` again) and redundant classes (given you have `d-none`, you don't need `d-sm-none` at all). I'd suggest `class="d-none d-md-block col-3 my-col"` is all you need (again, you don't need the responsive `col-md-3` version because it'll only be shown above that breakpoint anyway). In general, it'd help if you could be specific in your question - saves us all time and effort!